# Java program to expose COM object

Tags: java, dll

Can someone help me write a java program to access a method in a COM DLL file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello joules, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please be more specific in asking your problem? If you give us some more context or a short snippet of some example code or error to let us know what you specifically need help on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the ActiveX controls that are sometimes available in Windows DLL ?
If it is the case, I fear it will be difficult to call any of their methods except by a Windows C, C++ or C# program.